# My keyboard is making weird clicking noises and some keys are acting strange

Tags: keyboard, clicking-sound

So when I was making dinner, my cat sat down on my laptops keyboard and now it's not functioning like it should... Every time I press a button, there is this weird clicking sound and I have to wait a few seconds before I can type the same button twice. Please help me because it's really annoying! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Check under the keys, make sure that you don't have any hair or sticky refuse left over in between or underneath the keys. This isn't really a superuser question, but I understand you need help.

Comment: Go into the control panel and check your Ease of Use/Accessibility Center settings, they may have been turned on.

Comment: Does this sound comes from speakers or just some keyboard sound. It may be `Sticky Keys` or `Filter Keys` got enabled due to prolonged pressing of `Shift` Keys.

Comment: Amazing, a question posed by someone with 1 rep after 5 years, who didn't care to accept or comment any of the 3 answers, and 40K views who didn't care to up or downvote; anyway the question did not show any research effort

Answer (score 1):

Get your laptop keyboard replaced by the manufacturer or  authorized dealer. Some repair centers have some weird gum for this keyboard key thing.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too.  (Although, mine was from a child not a cat.)  I held the shift key down until it stopped making noises(there was a series of clicks and finally a beep) and then the keyboard worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For a classic desktop keyboard you will want to remove each key one by one, by gently prying up to remove it. Be gentle. Take a photo of the keyboard so you remember where the key go. Once the keys are all removed wipe out any dust, potato chip left overs and anything that could prevent the keyboard from working properly. This should resolve your issue. Also then be sure to add the keys back on.

I have done this for years. Usually some piece of something gets under a key and makes this noise.